# Partial Differential Equation trouble

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have to solve the partial differential equation $t\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0$

I make $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$, and after deriving and replacing I got the ordinary differential equations $X'(x)+ \lambda X(x)=0$ and $T''(t)+\frac{\lambda T(t)}{t}=0$.

I have no problems with the first ODE (the X one), but I'm not pretty sure how to solve the second (the T one). I tried separating variables ($\frac{T''(t)}{T(t)}=-\frac{\lambda}{t}$) but then I got in a dead point.

Thanks.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryFunctions.html

Comment: Assuming you have separated variables correctly, such an ODE admits solutions in terms of Bessel functions: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html

Comment: A typographical detail: I have changed your "d" into $\partial$ (in Latex "partial" symbol)

Comment: There is a sign mistake in one of the two ODEs.